# Render Shadeless Image as Background with Cycles in Blender 2.9

Tags: image

How can I make a png image with an alpha mask shadless, meaning the image, which I want to use it as a background, won't be affected (washed out) by the lights in the scene?
I am currently using Blender 2.91. From tutorials, in older version of Blender, there was a shadless option somewhere in the material properties but I can not find it in my current version of Blender.[image]

Simple example is provided in the screenshot below.

Regards

Comment: Just plug image texture node directly to output node.

Comment: Or you can use Import image as plane ... There is under properties (N) an option Shadeless that sets material for you.